# Why can't I publish the game?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-games, applovin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIz4m.png)I select arm64 (64 bit)  and x86 and amrv7 and select build app bundle in player setting 
so but when I want publish so I have an error like :

Error

This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 2.
Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app.

All plugin worked in my other game but A plug in i new(=applovin sdk), this is a system ads , How can I understand applovin sdk support for 64 bit ?

Why can't I publish the game?
please help me

I have this problem some week and can not publish my games ? please help me
What is my wrong?

Comment: Are you using any native plugins that only have 32-bit binaries?

Comment: this is the other possibility. a library or plugin that you are using in the project is adding 32bit reference to the projects build. to check for this ask yourself what packages you added and look to see if any of them relate to Android specific functionality.

Comment: All plugin worked in my other game but A plug in i new(=applovin), this is a system ads , How can I understand applovin  support for 64 bit?

Comment: I have updated the answer below with what to do if you suspect it is native plugin related.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project properties, Switch to project back end IL2CPP.

Android project properties -> https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html
IL2CPP setting -> https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP.html

other stuff that you probably already did:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildSettings.html

- switch platform -> to Android
- ensure you have API compatibility set, and that you have downloaded the required API versions via the Android NPK tooling.

Based on your error you could also try temporarily disabling the ARM7 option.

*[update]*
Based on OP's response, while the above is general troubleshooting, it seems to be native plugin. If this is the case use the following technique to determine if the plugin is 32 bit.
1. Create a new android project, make sure it builds. set ARM64 and not ARM7 in project settings.
2. add just the plugin. Rebuild the project.
3. If there is an exception related to the platform it may be the plugin is 32 bit.

*If you get an error*

1. First check the error, it may not be related (i.e. a red herring).
2. Go back to the plugin site, check for 64 bit, also check if the plugin has git source such as on GitHub. 
   If it does you can probably recompile the plugin to 64 bit (separate question).

Comment: I did all of them , So I have This Error also

Comment: I could solve my problem by disabling the x86 target architecture.

Comment: Anonymous Type , Hello , I have two questions: 1- what is NPK? and how Can I download it? 2-What is plugin 64bit ?I downloaded sdk api(16 to 29) +NDK 16 for unity 2019.1.9 so what is link plugin 64 bit on GITHUB?

Comment: @afshin if you are using Unity, and you selected Android options during Unity install, then you will have the recommended version of the Android NPK. When you go to project settings does it list the NPK as available or is the box for NPK empty?
If you are now getting errors with the NPK "missing" or the version version of an SDK API missing you should either check existing questions or make a new question. You don't need the github source for the plugin unless it is 32bit only and you require 64bit. this would only be for older unmaintained plugins.

Comment: @afshin if you dont know what NPK is i suspect you may have skipped over several configuration steps in your quest to publish a working app. Please review the setup documentation for android projects and ensure all steps in Unity are completed. 
i.e. make sure android components are installed, and verify the NPK - which you will know once you go through the setup configuration for Unity.

Comment: further reading of your question suggests you are quite familliar with android projects. im not sure why you haven't come across NPK before. Look given you know there is a 64bit problem with the plugin, i think you should check with the vendor or project site for either:
A. source code - so you can compile it yourself to 64bit
B. a 64 bit version of the plugin. 

if its 32bit and you need 64 bit no amount of fiddling with the exisitng 32bit plugin is going to make the error go away.you need 64bit plugin or you need to remove it and replace the functionality in your app with something else.

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm replying a bit late, but i think the solution is to just:

- Enable IL2CPP
- Disable x86